# AngularJs 2.0 built-in components - How to use them correctly

Tags: angular

Angular 2 provides a number of built-in components. Such as NgIf, NgFor, NgStyle, NgNonBindable....  Some of the components were used with an '*', such as *ngIf and *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="item of items">
   {{item}}
</div>
```

Some of them were used with '[]', such as [ngStyle] and [ngClass]: (Component inputs?)

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'yellow'}">Content</div>
```

And some were used like 'Angular-1': for example:

```
<div ngNonBindable>
   Angular code snippet: {{content}}
</div>
```

Does anyone here know why? and what's the differences? How do I remember the way to use them correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular 2 directives which cause some kind of change to the DOM like ngIf for conditionally added/removed blocks or ngFor - for repeated ones are marked with asterisk "*".

ngStyle and ngClass are used with "[]" because this causes a [one way data binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) to the desired property of the element with the passed value.

Some of the directives like ngNonBindable are used in Angular 1 style because theirs using don't require data binding to surround them with "[]" or banana in box syntax "[()]" (two way data binding), but provide information for the Angular core about the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, these are all equivalent:

```
{{ expression }}              
[target] = "expression"       
bind-target = "expression"
```

`{{ expression }}` is interpolation and one way binding 
`[ expression ]` is also one way binding 
`( event )` is for events like (click)

`[(ngModel)]` is for two way binding that is the same as this:

```
<input type="text" 
       [value] = "character.name"
       (input) = "character.name = $event.target.value />
```

`*ngFor` and `*ngIf` are Structural Directives, the `*` denotes changing the DOM