# Using *ngFor for create a series of radio buttons for angular2 using materialize-css framework

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, materialize, typescript2.0

Seasons greetings everyone!

I have the following code that constructs a single radio-button based on the materialize-css framework http://materializecss.com/forms.html#radio

```
<input name = 'group1'
       type = 'radio'
       id = 'test2'/>
<label for = 'test2'>Yellow</label>
```

My attempt at using *ngFor is shown below:

```
  statuses: string[] = [
    'Single',
    'Married',
    'Divorced',
    'Common-law',
    'Visiting'
  ];

  <p>{{maritalStatus?.status}}</p>
  <div *ngFor = 'let status of statuses;  let indx = index'>
    <input #widget
           class = 'with-gap'
           name = 'statusGroup'
           type = 'radio'
           id = 'status'
           [value] = 'status'
           [(ngModel)] = 'maritalStatus.status'
           (change) = 'radioBtnChange$.next(status)'
    />
    <label for = 'status'>{{status}}</label>
    <p>{{status}}{{ indx}}</p>
  </div>
```

All buttons are created but only the first button (Single) can be selected.

How can I get the series of button to function as radio-buttons are expected to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d4zBlPJVHWrcWQAM3q64?p=preview)

## Why it's not working

The `status` variable in your `*ngFor` loop is not being used in the `for` attribute of your `label` or the `id` attribute of your `input`.

There are two options to fix this:

## [Template expressions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions)

You can use a template expression by putting the attributes in square brackets like this:

`<input [id]="status">`

which is what you did (correctly) with the `value` attribute.

> A template expression produces a value. Angular executes the expression and assigns it to a property of a binding target; the target might be an HTML element, a component, or a directive.

## [Interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation)

You can use interpolation by using double-curly braces like this:

`<input id="{{status}}">`

> More generally, the material between the braces is a template expression that Angular first evaluates and then converts to a string.

## What's the difference?

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35944965/5357459) for an explanation on the differences between these methods.

## Full Template Html

```
<h2>Current Status</h2>
<p>{{maritalStatus?.status}}</p>

<h2>Options</h2>
<div *ngFor="let status of statuses; let indx = index">
  <input #widget
   class='with-gap'
   name='statusGroup'
   type='radio'
   [id]='status'
   [value]='status'
   [(ngModel)]='maritalStatus.status'
  />
  <label [for]='status'>{{status}}</label>
</div>
```

## Full Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  maritalStatus = { status: 'Nothing selected' };
  statuses: string[] = [
    'Single',
    'Married',
    'Divorced',
    'Common-law',
    'Visiting'
  ];
  constructor() { }

}
```

## Update - Angular 2 versions < 2.2.0

If you're using an Angular 2 version that is less than 2.2.0 you need to explicitly set the `label`'s `for` attribute like this:

```
<label [attr.for]='status'>{{status}}</label>
```

because `for` is not a property of `label` elements.

## Why?

Since [Angular 2.2.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#220-upgrade-firebooster-2016-11-14) ([634b3bb](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/634b3bb88beec51d86dfde5228c95c57a54ba8af)), Angular maps the `for` attribute to the related `htmlFor` property.

It sounds like a lot of developers intuitively [expected this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7516), so they added it.

This was all pretty confusing for me at first, and [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/11/angular-2-template-syntax-demystified-part-1.html) by Pascal Precht really cleared up a lot of questions.

Comment: Great, and thanks. Two small tweaks I had to make to get it running - both id on the input and for on the label are attributes, NOT properties. Hence I had to prefix both with attr for it to work. See EDIT1 above for what works for me. Thanks

Comment: Actually, only a single tweak is necessary - the one for label since id is both a property and an attribute.

Comment: I just found out that it's only needed if you're using an Angular 2 version that is less than 2.2.0.. I was pretty confused at first, and it turns out they added this as a feature recently. Thanks for pointing it out as it led to some fun learning about the framework!