# What does Angular 2 hashtags in template mean?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am working with angular 2 and I have found something like

```
<input #searchBox (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)"
```

and it works.

However, I don't understand the meaning of **#searchBox**. I haven't found anything clear neither in the doc.

Could anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2) - "*On a DOM element <div #mydiv> a reference to the element*". In other words, having `#searchBox` on the element is what allows you to use `searchBox.value` in the keyup handler.

Comment: its a variable.

Answer (score 255):

It's syntax used in the Angular 2 templating system which declares DOM elements as variables.

Here I give my component a template URL:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'harrys-app',
   templateUrl: 'components/harry/helloworld.component.html'
})

export class HarrysApp {}
```

Templates render HTML. In a template you can use data, property binding and event binding. This is accomplished with the following syntax:

`#`     - variable declaration

`()`    - event binding

`[]`    - property binding

`[()]`  - two-way property binding

`{{ }}` - interpolation

`*`     - structural directives

The `#` syntax can declare local variable names which references DOM objects in a template.
e.g.

```
 <span [hidden]="harry.value">*</span>
 <input type="text" #harry>
 {{ harry.value }}
```

Comment: Working example: `<input #bla style="display: none;" value="Foo" /<div> {{bla.value}} </div>`. Foo is displayed in div.

Comment: And there is no way for that variable declaration itself to be a variable? I am trying to create material menu items from a complex nested object of menus and this has stymied me. I can't seem to dynamically create the dom variables. Do they really need to be hard-coded in the dom?

Comment: Official Document Reference: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Comment: Can one element have more than one hashtag variable declarations?

Comment: Two-way property binding syntax `[()]` can be easily remembered by the catchphrase "banana in a box".

Answer (score 81):

When you set this #searchBox, you can get this input on your Typescript like

```
    @ViewChild('searchBox') searchBox;
    console.info(searchBox.nativeElement.value)
```

**EDIT**

Adding some example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU?p=preview

Answer (score 43):

From [angulartraining.com](https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-the-magic-of-template-reference-variables-3183f0a0d9d1):

> **Template reference variables** are a little gem that allows to get a lot of nice things done with Angular. I usually call that feature “the hashtag syntax” because, well, it relies on a simple hashtag to create a reference to an element in a template:
>
> ```
> <input #phone placeholder="phone number">
> ```
>
> What the above syntax does is fairly simple: It creates a reference to the **input** element that can be used later on in my template. Note that the scope for this variable is the entire HTML template in which the reference is defined.
>
> Here’s how I could use that reference to get the value of the input, for instance:
>
> ```
> <!-- phone refers to the input element --> 
> <button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>
> ```
>
> Note that **phone** refers to the [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) object instance for the **input**. As a result, **phone** has all of the properties and methods of any HTMLElement (id, name, innerHTML, value, etc.)
>
> The above is a nice way to avoid using ngModel or some other kind of data binding in a simple form that does not require much in terms of validation.
>
> ---
>
> **Does this also work with components?**
>
> The answer is YES!
>
> ... the best part of it is that we’re getting a reference to the actual component instance, HelloWorldComponent, so we can access any methods or properties of that component (even if they are declared as private or protected, which is surprising):
>
> ```
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-hello',
>   // ...
>
> export class HelloComponent {
>    name = 'Angular';
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> <app-hello #helloComp></app-hello>
>
> <!-- The following expression displays "Angular" -->
> {{helloComp.name}}
> ```

Comment: "even if they are declared as private or protected, which is surprising" - keep in mind that access specifiers are a compile time guard, and typically don't do anything after the code is compiled and running.

Answer (score 27):

It creates a template variable that references

- the `input` element if the element is a plain DOM element
- the component or directive instance if it is an element with a component or directive
- some specific component or directive if it's used like `#foo="bar"` when `bar` is

```
@Directive({ // or @Component
  ...
  exportAs: 'bar'
})
```

Such a template variable can be referenced in template bindings or in element queries like

```
@ViewChild('searchBox') searchBox:HTMLInputElement;
```

Comment: This is amazing. By the way - it's pretty similar to the ngModel, isn't it?

Comment: Not really. `ngModel` is for forms integration. You can do all other kinds of bindings without `ngModel`.

Comment: Last thing, how did you use `ngAfterViewInit` without actually importing it? And implementing? It's a build in feature on plunker?

Comment: No, Angular doesn't depend on the lifecycle interfaces be declared explicitely. If the method exists it gets called. Implementing the interfaces explicitely is good practice though.