# what is the use of #attribute in html5 using angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-template

I'm new at angular 2. I want to know, what is **#something**. What it is for?
for example:

```
<div #something></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677096/what-does-angular-2-hashtags-in-template-mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Angular 2 hashtags in template mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677096/what-does-angular-2-hashtags-in-template-mean)

Answer (score 0):

## is used to declare a local variable.

You can use it to assign some value that you might want to use

```
<div #something="localVar"> </div>
```