# What does #group="matButtonToggleGroup" mean?

Tags: angular, button, angular-material

Taken from [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples):

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
  <mat-button-toggle value="left" aria-label="Text align left">
    <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="center" aria-label="Text align center">
    <mat-icon>format_align_center</mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="right" aria-label="Text align right">
    <mat-icon>format_align_right</mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="justify" disabled aria-label="Text align justify">
    <mat-icon>format_align_justify</mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
<div class="example-selected-value">Selected value: {{group.value}}</div>
```

What does `#group` mean? Normally, it means [variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677786/426227), but here it must mean something different. If I don't use *matButtonToggleGroup* as value I get

> Template parse errors:
>   There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matButtonToggleGroup2"

I [saw](https://hoshcoding.com/courses/1/angular-material-button-toggle) that there is also a `#toggleGroup`. In the [official API documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api) I can't find something about both.

Comment: This usage can be used to creates a reference to the directive which has (exportAs: 'matButtonToggleGroup2')
 U can look at this example 

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582293/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-template-in-angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#group` - is a template reference variable which you can name however you want

`matButtonToggleGroup` - is a **exportAs** which is a name under which the component instance is exported in a template. You can't change it unless you have access to the original directive

```
                         #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
                        /              \
template reference variable         exportAs
```

`exportAs` name is defined in `MatButtonToggleGroup` directive https://github.com/angular/components/blob/92bbc77050a911f6614ce55280b5cc8e634d9ac0/src/material/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L108

You can think of `exportAs` as a public API for directive. If there are too many directives on one element you can get reference to specific directive by knowning its exportAs name.

See also

- [What is #auto attribute here and why it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required)