# What does the syntax #foo="myFoo" in template mean?

Tags: angular

I understand the what hashtag syntax `<input #myinput >` means, providing a name for access to the element, but I don't understand the following syntax, from an example in the angular material website:

```
 <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
```

What does the expression after the equal sign mean?  Is it some kind of aliasing?  If so why not just write `<mat-menu #matMenu>` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Angular 2 hashtags in template mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677096/what-does-angular-2-hashtags-in-template-mean)

Comment: Not really, as this discussion just is on the syntax "#name", not #name='[something]'.  However that question is answered in the answer below (4th bullet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *#* you can create a reference so you can call from other places in your component.
As the documentation says:

> A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element
> within a template. It can also refer to a directive (which contains a
> component), an element, TemplateRef, or a web component

Angular assigns each template reference variable a value based on where you declare the variable:

- If you declare the variable on a component, the variable refers to the component instance.
- If you declare the variable on a standard HTML tag, the variable refers to the element.
- If you declare the variable on an  element, the variable refers to a TemplateRef instance, which represents the template.
- ***If the variable specifies a name on the right-hand side***, such as `#var="ngModel"`, the variable refers to the directive or component on the element with a matching `exportAs` name.

You can read more here: [template-reference-variables | angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)

Comment: What does this mean? If you declare the variable on a component... How do we declare a variable on the component?

Comment: With the hash. (ex:  `<div #adiv></div>`. You can now use the `adiv` because you have created a reference. You can access it from your `.ts` file as well as an `ElementRef` cause is a standar HTML tag.

Comment: It appears that what appears after the equals sign is not a variable name but a type.  So when you go #menu="matMenu" or #var="ngModel" you are identifying that the object referred to my 'menu' or 'var' is a directive of type of matMenu or ngModel respectively.  Or at least that what it seems like.

Comment: How does that differ from "If you declare the variable on a standard HTML tag, the variable refers to the element"  both are on an htmlelement one refers to the component and the other to the element?  Doesn't make sense. I still don't understand the "Component" part.

Comment: I do not understand what you don't understand. Yes Template-Reference-Variable works the same, it creates a reference wherever you put it. In the Component you can: `<my-component #mycomp></my-comp>`. And now you can refer to this specific instance from other places. Just like an ElementReference but now we have MyComponent Reference.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer is correct and links to a document with the answer, I thought it was worth unpacking the explanation a bit more.

**tl;dr** – this syntax `#var="directiveExportAsName"` is useful for targeting a specific directive on an element if there are *multiple* directives applied to the element.

#### Long answer

Specifically, it is unpacked in the ["Variable specifying a name"](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#variable-specifying-a-name) section.

The code example being:

```
<form #itemForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(itemForm)">
 <!-- removed for brevity -->
</form>

<div [hidden]="!itemForm.form.valid">
  <p>{{ submitMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

Their explanation (emphasis mine):

> The `NgForm` directive demonstrates getting a reference to a different value by referencing a directive's `exportAs` name...
> **Without the `ngForm` attribute value, the reference value of `itemForm` would be the `HTMLFormElement`, `<form>`**. If an element is an Angular Component, a reference with no attribute value will automatically reference the component instance. Otherwise, a reference with no value will reference the DOM element, **even if the element has one or more directives applied to it.**

For this particular case `<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">`, although the [official examples](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) use it, I don't think it is necessary. According to the doc, "If an element is an Angular Component, a reference with no attribute value will automatically reference the component instance," and since [the selector `mat-menu` and exported as name `matMenu` refer to the same component directive](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenu), it is therefore redundant.