# In Angular for which arrtributes we have to use parentheses and for which we have to use bracket

Tags: angular

I am a bit confused about using parentheses and brackets on attributes in Angular.

```
<form [formGroup]="vform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(vform.value)">
  <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User Name" formControlName="uname">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Full Name" formControlName="fname">
  <input type="submit" [disabled]="!vform.valid" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what is the question

Comment: where we have to use parentheses and brackets, for ngSubmit we used parentheses and for disabled we used brackets. so I'm confusing for what attributes we use those?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: The documentation is quite clear on this issue. Please read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses for binding to events like `(click)="clickHandler()"`

Use square brackets for binding to properties like `[disabled]="true"`

Use both (referred to as football in a box) for two-way binding like `[(ngModel)]="attr"`

Comment: (click) its for view to component.(one way)
[disabled] its for component to view(one way)
[(ngModel)] its 2 way binding

Answer (score 2):

Where ever you are passing a property down to the component/element, you'd use brackets like :

Say I'm passing `size="20"` to the div element

```
<div size="20"></div> // passing a value , not a VARIABLE 

<div [size]="sizeVariable"></div> // passing a variable to be bound to
```

To give you a broader view, imagine when using normal `style` tag, you're passing some properties ( in this case styles like colour and ... ) to the element :

```
<div style="color:red">
```

Where as when using parantesese , you're subscribing to the event that is coming up from the element :

```
<div (click)="doSomething()">
```

is similar to :

```
<div onClick="doSomething">
```

and is somewhat similar to

```
 $('#yourElement').on('click',doSomething)
```

Answer (score 1):

**`[]`** is for binding from a value.It allows to pass objects.

```
<div [allowed]="allowed"></div>
```

**`()`** is for binding an event handler to be called when a DOM event is fired

```
<date-comp [title]="childTitle" (notify)="onNotification($event)"></date-comp>
```

Refer **[`What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2/35945054)**

Answer (score 0):

Parantheses is used for function calling while brackets used to pass or set an attribute. For more go through angular documentation @ www.angular.io