# How to get and send id from option Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need your help. I have a small piece of code. In my template I have `select` from `option` in which I save the list of settings. Each individual setting has its own `id`. I also have an interface through which I have a data model - the fields that I will send or receive from the backend. Please help with the task: how do I get the `id` option I choose and send it in the `optionId` field? Thank you very much

interface.ts

```
export interface IData {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   optionId: any;
}
```

html

```
<select formControlName="templateListValue">
   <option *ngFor="let tempItem of templateListOptions" [value]="templateItem.id">
     {{tempItem.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

ts

```
public getIdFromTemplate() {
   return this.templateListOptions.find
 ((element: ITemplateData) => element.id === this.form.controls.templateListValue.value);
}
```

Comment: Option is just an option the user chooses, actual value is stored in the Select element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136548/angular-4-using-objects-for-option-values-in-a-select-list

Comment: you might use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45137528/1769563
or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776357/1769563

Answer (score 0):

You can use **valueChanges** to observe your control for changes and then find the element.

```
this.formGroup.controls.templateListValue.valueChanges.subscribe(id => {
    const element = this.templateListOptions.find((element: ITemplateData) => element.id === id);
    console.log(element);
    console.log(element.optionId)
})
```

Comment: Did your problem solve? any question?