# function is not defined when in <select> scope

Tags: html, angular, typescript

With the following code

```
<form>
    <select class="attkOptions" *ngFor="let subString of Attack.currentText" placeholder="" onchange="dumpValue(value)">
        <option [value]="{'index':Attack.currentText.indexOf(subString)}">{{subString.text}}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of subString.options" [value]="{'index':Attack.currentText.indexOf(subString),'option':option}">
            {{option}}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and component

```
export class Patterns implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
 ...
    dumpValue(object) {
        console.log(object.index);
        
    }
 ...
}
```

I am getting the following error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: dumpValue is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (module:18:9)`. I am able to call functions in my class in other points of the code, so my deduction is that by using it within ngFor, I somehow leave the scope of my class (and in fact, calling the function elsewhere in code works as expected.

How can I specify the scope of function to be within my class?

Comment: You shouldnt use native event handlers and use angular handlers instead.
It should be `(change)="dumpValue(option)"`.

Comment: Thanks. Using `(change)="dumpValue(option)"` has allowed me to reference the function, but passing `option`/`value`/`$option`/'$value' still wont allow me to pass the input value as parameter. I found that passing `$event` works, but is there a way that would allow me to pass the object generated in the <options>'s [value]="...", without having to subscribe to changes?

Comment: Have you tried using `$event.target.value`? You can only pass `subString`, `$event` or any other variable in the current scope but nothing which is nested (like value)

Comment: Yes, passing `$event.target.value` is what I do at the moment. I also noticed that I cannot have value be represented by object of variables `{...}`, but having string or array `[...]` worked just fine. When using `{'index':Attack.currentText.indexOf(subString),'option':option}`, the result is just [Object Object], but `['index':Attack.currentText.indexOf(subString),'option':option]` results in a string, which I can split and then put into new object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136548/angular-4-using-objects-for-option-values-in-a-select-list