# What's the difference between an Ionic 4 component's "property" vs "attribute"?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/col

For column width, it says that sizeLg is the property and size-lg is the attribute. Which do I use and why? When?

This:

```
<ion-col size-lg="6"></ion-col>
```

Or this:

```
<ion-col sizeLg="6"></ion-col>
```

Or this:

```
<ion-col [size-lg]="6"></ion-col>
```

Or this:

```
<ion-col [sizeLg]="6"></ion-col>
```

...all seem like things I could do but I'm not sure why and when I would want either and it's not clear in the documentation.

In the context of Ionic, why is sizeLg a property and size-lg is an attribute, and what are the implications?

Comment: Reference to a good answer explaining the differences in Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35944965/3061152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how far the Ionic 4 documentation improved compared to its pre-release state, but your question actually touches the underlying Stencil builder and its designed behaviour, especially for non-Angular usage, i.e. as bare Web Components.

A quick answer is: attributes directly reflect properties, generalizing the Angular properties binding so that it works in a very similar way even outside Angular.

Therefore if you use Ionic 4 within Angular, all 4 syntaxes should work (i.e. be functionnally equivalent), with `[sizeLg]="6"` being probably the most familiar form.

Stencil is the build tool powering Ionic 4, compiling it as Web Components (Custom Elements). In Stencil, you design your Component in a somehow mixed fashion of Angular/React, and the compiler transforms all your Input properties as JS properties and HTML attributes, mimicking the API of other standard HTML Elements. Think about an `<input type="checkbox">` element and its `checked` attribute, which is also a read/write JS property (you can do `document.querySelector("input").checked = true`).

Stencil does that for its output Web Components, reflecting all exposed JS input properties (usually in camelCase) as HTML attributes (in their equivalent snake-case type), so that you can define inputs in any of both ways, like standard HTML Elements, even if you do not use Angular.

But with this, you would be limited to `[size-lg]="6"` when using it in Angular (and the non square bracket form, of course). So Ionic adds an Angular wrapper that tells Angular that there is an underlying `@Input() sizeLg` property, and now you can use the more Angular style `[sizeLg]="6"` form.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<ion-col size-lg="6"></ion-col>
```

and

```
<ion-col sizeLg="6"></ion-col>
```

both are the same, but in Ionic 4 they introduce this `sizeLg` syntax because is a javascript standard for variable names
.
I recomend to use this way

```
<ion-col sizeLg="6"></ion-col>
```

and

```
<ion-col [size-lg]="6"></ion-col>
<ion-col [sizeLg]="6"></ion-col>
```

are used when the thing after `=` is a variable in the code.

Comment: This definitely helps with this particular use but in general what's the difference between a property and an attribute?

Comment: I hope this helps: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28085/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property the first two answers define the difference very simple.

Comment: Yeah I understand the definition what I don't understand is within Ionic context why is sizeLg a property and size-lg is an attribute, and what are the implications?