# More reading on ngx-datatable-columns

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

New to ngx-datatable. In search for advanced display options I saw plenty `ngx-datatable-column`, but it's not in [ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/) nor any explanation from google.
Can someone tell me where I learn about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some [info about `ngx-datatable-column` here.](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column)

In addition, there is an article about [inputs in `ngx-datatable-column`](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs)

Moreover, try to [see their Github docs page](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/tree/master/docs/api/column). Just click on files such as **inputs.md, internals.md, modes.md**

Comment: Nice! `<ngx-datatable-column>` is the HTML counterpart of typescript **API Column**.  Tried the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-summary-ghw4kl?file=app/app.component.html) provided by you from another thread, most attributes/directives of `ngx-datatable-column` don't use brackets, but `summaryFunc` does. Out of curiosity, once added `[ ]` to those without, i.e. name to `[name]` won't work. Is there a rule? Thank you

Comment: @Jeb50 yeah, if it is property of component, then you need to set square brackets. Please, see this [post about parenthesis, brackets and asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2)