# angular what is the (change) in parenthesis concept called and what are all the options?

Tags: angular

I'm going through some angular code with the following snippet. What is the part with `(change)` called? What keywords should I use to Google this? I've also seen `(click)`. What other options are there?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('visualtitle', $event.target.checked)" />
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax (I'd also recommend going through a structured tutorial - https://angular.io/tutorial).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

They are called event bindings:
https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

If you would use vanilla html then the equivalent of `(click)` would be:

```
<button onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
```

Please see the attached link to the documentation. It explains it much better than I can :)