# What is the difference and if there is any difference what are those? text="string" vs [text]="'string'"

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I stumbled across a minor difference and I couldn't figure out what the difference is, if there are any.

e.g:

```
<kendo-label class="k-display-block" [for]="list" [text]="'find user'"> </kendo-label>
```

and

```
<kendo-label class="k-display-block" [for]="list" text="Nutzer finden"> </kendo-label>
```

notice the double quotation marks in the first line of code.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: also: [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses property binding, wherin you can bind javascript expressions or properties/functions of a class to attributes and pass them to child component. You can identify the bindings by.

> [test] <- property binding (one way binding - from ts updates the html)
>
> (test) <- event binding (one way binding - from html updates the ts)
>
> [(ngModel)] <- both bindings (two way binding - does both the actions of the above bindings)

So in the below expression text is expecting a javascript expression, without the quotes it cannot understand if its a string, it will just error out, trying to find
some property called `find` eventhough its a string.

```
<kendo-label class="k-display-block" [for]="list" [text]="'find user'"> </kendo-label>
```

In the below code there is no binding, so by default it will passed as string and its pure html, no angular bindings involved!

```
<kendo-label class="k-display-block" [for]="list" text="Nutzer finden"> </kendo-label>
```