# the Difference between [routerLink] and routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular14

what is the difference between [routerLink] and routerLink in angular routing  ? and what is the benifits for each one and what I should use

know the difference

Comment: `[routerLink]` indicates the value you will provide is dynamic, otherwise it's a static value. This is true of any property in Angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property):

> The brackets, [], cause Angular to evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment as a dynamic expression.
> Without the brackets, Angular treats the right-hand side as a string literal and sets the property to that static value.